# Reload tableView data in rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to get my tableView in rootViewController to reload after I create a new object in the array that populates it.

I want to use the following in my viewDidLoad of rootVIewController:

`[tableView reloadDate];`

but I get the error:

`Use of undeclared identifier "tableView"`

I think it's because I haven't declared the object tableView until after the viewDidLoad method. So what other options do I have to refresh the table?

Thanks

Comment: `tableView` in this case is ivar. I assume that you have property `tableView`. Try to write `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't declared the tableView, than you cannot tell it to reload. There is something of a question surrounding the architecture of your application: When you say 'rootViewCOntroller' - is that referring to the applications RVC? If so, are you instantiating the tableView programmatically, or accessing it from a .xib/outlet?

If you're accessing a XIB, you should be calling your property outlet [[self tableView] reloadData].

If you're creating the table view programmatically, you should create it before you call reload on it -- and in most cases, you'll want to define a property on your RVC class pointing to that tableView, such that you'd still be calling [[self tableView] reloadData] as opposed to accessing it directly as you've done in your code.

Comment: Sorry about the weird terms,(new to obj-c), It's the apps RVC I'm referring to. I am instantiating tableView programmatically.

Comment: So it sounds like you're instantiating your tableView later than you need to be. Is there a motivation for not simply creating the table earlier in your code? I'm also not clear on how adding new objects to the array bears on the RVCs viewDidLoad... Assuming you've got the table on screen, if a new model object is added to the array, you should tell the tableView to reload at that time (or use a [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths])... again I can't see your architecture, but by the time something's added to the array, viewDidLoad is long gone...

Comment: I think my problem is that the object is being added to the array in another class so I don't know how to reloadData from one class for another

Comment: There's a few ways to approach this but you might try delegation. Define a simple protocol on whatever class is managing your tableView, give it a method like 'modelObjectInserted:'. Conform any classes that could potentially insert objects to the protocol you've defined. Whenever a conforming class will insert an object, it should also then call this delegate method. When the method is invoked on your table view controller, you can take then take appropriate action, for example calling reload or insertCellForRowAtIndexPath...